# Compact Framework Socket Documents Printing

Tags: c#, sockets, compact-framework

I'm trying to print a document to a network laser printer from a windows ce device.
Since i'm trying to print sample text there are no problems and i can do that trought sockets, my problem is that i need to print some text and a small image below the text, for example:

```
not formatted text
------------------
|    IMAGE       |
------------------
other not formatted text
```

My first idea was build an Rtf document and send it to the printer trought sokets, but it's obviously print the document text content and not the text formatted... I try many other ways to encode the data to send but without results... there is a way to do that or i'm only wasting my time? If not, there is a way to archieve that sending PCL/PostScript data? (Usually the driver are "standard" for basic commands on the new laser printers).
That's the function i use to print on the network printer:

```
public static string print_data_to_IP(string printerIP, int printerPort, byte[] myEncoded_bytes)
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            //Not supported
            //socket.NoDelay = true;

            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(printerIP);
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, printerPort);
            socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            socket.Send(myEncoded_bytes);
            socket.Close();
            return null;
        }
```

and myEncoded_bytes is made by:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (FileStream stream = File.Open("\\test.rtf", FileMode.Open))
            {
                byte[] stream_to_byte_array = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(stream_to_byte_array, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                ms = new MemoryStream(stream_to_byte_array);
                stream.Close();
            }
byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
```

thanks for the help,

Legion

P.S.: External library are not allowed, so i cannot user printCE or similar 'helps'.

Comment: First question is: What printer languages are supported by the printer? If PCL, you need to encode the Bitmap Image as a PCL raster graphic, then send the encoded data to the printer. See HP PCL Programmer Reference (example: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/277365/Hp-Pcl-5.html?page=339). If the printer is capable to print PostScript, you need to encode the print data as PostScript commands.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'll check the link. Obviously the printer support both, so i only need to select the "smooth" way :) Sending PCL (or PS) commands trought sockets should work right? 
Thanks again.

Comment: You can send the printer every raw commands using his printer language. If the printer is HP PJL compatible you can use PJL to switch the printer language (http://www.frankworsley.com/blog/2011/1/23/printing-directly-to-a-network-printer). As you do not want to use a library (valid for open source too?), you have to encode the bitmap in the native printer language, Postscript or PCL. Postscript is a programming language using a stack (http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/postscript/), wheras PCL is a simple sequencial language. Good luck! If the printer is PDF compatible, look at iTextSharpCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sry i try to explain better how i reach the goal, that's an example function that is made following @josef [link](http://www.frankworsley.com/blog/2011/1/23/printing-directly-to-a-network-printer), i write some text in a choosen position and draw a red box at the center of the screen (comments explain how pcl commands works).
Following a PCL manual you can easily customize text and drawings as you like ([HERE_AN_HP_MANUAL](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/bpl13210.pdf)).

```
        private void btn_pcl_printing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string printer_ip = "192.168.1.6";

            char command_start_character = '\u001B';
            char carriage_return = '\u000D';
            char line_feed = '\u000A';
            string lane_escape_character = string.Concat(carriage_return, line_feed); //"\r\n";
#if PJL
            string printer_process_name = "prova.TXT";
            string raw_end_of_file = command_start_character + "%–12345X" + " @PJL EOF" + lane_escape_character;
            raw_end_of_file += command_start_character + "%–12345X";
            string raw_to_print = command_start_character + "%–12345X";
            raw_to_print += " @PJL JOB NAME = \"" + printer_process_name  + "\"" + lane_escape_character;
            raw_to_print += " @PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PCL" + lane_escape_character;
#else
            //Reset the printer and start a new PAGE
            string raw_to_print = command_start_character + "E";
#endif
            //Set Printer resolution to 150 DPI
            string raw_pcl_commands = command_start_character + "&u150D" + command_start_character + "*t150R";
            //Write "Hello Wold!!" at the position 150x and 150y (the command is case sensitive).
            raw_pcl_commands += command_start_character + "*p150x150Y" + "Hello World!!!";
            //Another way to to what i've just done before
            //raw_pcl_commands += command_start_character + "*p150X" + command_start_character + "*p150Y" + "Hello World!!!";
            raw_pcl_commands += command_start_character + "*p150X" + command_start_character + "*p150Y" + "Hello World!!!";
            //I choose to use RGB colors (v6), select an rgb color (a0,b0,c0) and save it an a palette (i0) that i select (i0S). My selected color is RED (255,0,0)
            raw_pcl_commands += command_start_character + "*v6w255a0b0c0i0S";
            //Another way to to what i've just done before
            //raw_pcl_commands += command_start_character + "*v6W";
            //raw_pcl_commands += command_start_character + "*v255a0b0C" + command_start_character + "*v0i0S";
            //Draw a rectangle 300*150
            raw_pcl_commands += command_start_character + "*c300a150b5P";


            //COMANDI PCL
            raw_pcl_commands += command_start_character + "E";
            raw_to_print += raw_pcl_commands;
#if PJL
            raw_to_print += raw_end_of_file;
#endif

            byte[] myEncoded_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(raw_to_print);
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            //Not supported on CE
            //socket.NoDelay = true;
            int printerPort = 9100;
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(printer_ip);
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, printerPort);
            socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            socket.Send(myEncoded_bytes);
            socket.Close();
        }
```

Now for the images you've 2 ways to follow:

1) Draw the image "manually" with PCL commands, [see from page 41 of that manual](http://www.undocprint.org/_media/formats/page_description_languages/pcl5_color_programming_quick_reference.pdf) to see some examples (if is a easy one like in my case that is a simple barcode is the best way to follow).

2) Draw the image with a PCL macro.... that's all i can say because read [that documentation](https://www.devenezia.com/docs/HP/index.html?1691) make me an headache and force me to choose method 1 :D

Hope that's help,
Legion